# Creating inner shadow in svg

Tags: svg, shadow, svg-filters

i'm new to svg and am trying to create inner shadow kind of similiar to the attached pic. I've tried the other stack-overflow answers but the shadow doesn't seems to be as strong as the png attached. Can the experts suggest any possible way of achieving the same?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

That doesn't look like a normal inset shadow - the opacity is too high near the border. So you'll have to do some fancy filtering to duplicate it. Here's something that will work for any shape:

```html
<svg width="600px" height="600px">
  <defs>
  <filter id="strong-inner">
    <feFlood flood-color="red"/>

<!-- This next operation subtracts the original shape from the red color 
field filling the filter region - which will give you a big color border 
surrounding the original shape -->
    <feComposite operator="out" in2="SourceGraphic" />

<!-- Next we want to expand the red border so it overlaps the space of the 
original shape - the radius 4 below will expand it by 4 pixels -->

    <feMorphology operator="dilate" radius="4"/>
    <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="5" />

<!-- After blurring it, we want to select just the parts of the blurred, 
expanded border that overlap the original shape - which we can do by using 
the 'atop' operator -->

    <feComposite operator="atop" in2="SourceGraphic"/>
  </filter>
  </defs>
  
  <rect x="10" y="10" width="500" height="500" fill="rgb(50, 0 , 200)" filter="url(#strong-inner)"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: can you explain what you mean by "the opacity is too high near the border"? This is an interesting approach but i dont think im seeing what it does differently compared to the other answer

Comment: Well two things: it works on any shape (filled path, circle etc.) not just a rect. And the shadow color is fully opaque at the border. You can see this more clearly if you increase the radius of the feMorphology.

Comment: yeah it definitely seems its the way to go for non-rect shapes, but just for rectangles, an inset box shadow w/ the right spread *appears* to achieve virtually identical results. i'll have to experiment more though...

Comment: this works for me for smaller stdDeviation but with larger values (ex. 30). The opacity still becomes lower.

Comment: Great solution!!! By the way, if saying *"normal inset shadow"* is about css drop-shadow than we have 4-th numeric option for fully opaque offset from border.

Comment: Ah - you're completely right - I'd forgotten there was a spread parameter in box-shadow. Yeah - for a rect - I'd go with box-shadow (if it works cross browser - Safari has pretty bad support for CSS properties on SVG subelements)

Answer (score 2):

We can use `box-shadow` with `inset` option.

```html
<svg style="background: rgb(51,54,148); width: 439px; height: 419px; box-shadow: 0 0 15px 6px inset rgba(255,0,96,0.8)"></svg>
```